# Extra screw after removing front wheel (plus enclosed hub brakes)

Tags: brakes, wheels

My partners bike, a Pashley Princess Sovereign, had a flat front tyre, and whilst I was out a friend came to have a look. He removed the front wheel (detaching the brake, a fully enclosed brake hub), and afterwards had a spare part left over, an eye bolt, pictured below
[image: extra part]

Would anyone know where this is likely to come from? If it shouldn't have come from the Pashley then it is possible that it was from another bike and had been there a while.

Comment: That appears to be a bolt for fastening a fender stay to the fender.

Comment: Does this bicycle have a fender? Can you include a picture of the front half of the bike, too?

Answer (score 1):

That is a fender (mudguard) mounting bolt. The hole in the bolt slides over the stay that attaches near the axle, and the threaded part goes through a bracket, normally on the mudguard but sometimes at the axle end.

[image]

[image]

The reason for that is safety - if the mudguard or stay gets caught in the wheel the stay pulls through that hole in the bolt rather than jamming in the wheel and stopping it. So you have a noise and rubbing rather than being thrown off the bike.